# How to change the field data type in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

```
"@version":{
              "type":"string",
              "index":"not_analyzed",
              "ignore_above":1024
           },
```

Here I have to change the type string to long .

I have used `curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/'` this is just a sample

Does anyone has any idea on this?

Comment: Are you using logstash to parse data?

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you are using dynamic mapping (which is by default), the type of a field depends of the type of data present in the field of the first indexed document.

So if the first indexed document has a field "version" of type string, the mapping will have a field "version" of type string.
[Documentation on the dynamic mapping.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/dynamic-mapping.html)

[You can't update a mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/mapping.html#_updating_existing_mappings). As explained in the documentation, you need to create a new index and reindex your data.

Comment: is there a way that before hand we can define the data type for all the mapping fields? For instance no matter what field comes in or gets created on the fly..i wish to hardcode and set it to string data type?

Comment: @MrunalGosar It is better to ask that in a new question, rather than a comment. Anyway, you can indicate the mappings when creating a new  index (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/mapping.html#_example_mapping). Or you can use an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/indices-templates.html), which then will be used when creating the index.

Comment: @baudsp..actually i thought your answer was somewhat related to issue that i am facing now..nvm i've asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036899/elasticsearch-mapping-select-all-fields-via-template-to-change-their-data-type-e