# Elasticsearch mapping select all fields via template to change their data type Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

Hi All I am using elasticsearch-template.json to set data type of all of my fields to string. Below is the snippet of the template:

```
{
    "template": "logstash-*",
    "settings": {
        "index.refresh_interval": "5s",
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 0
    },
    "mappings": {
        "logs": {
            "_all": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "properties": {
                "level1": {
                    "properties": {
                      "level2": {
                        "properties": {
                            "_all": {"type": "string"}
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here under level2 i have got lots of fields which get created i want to set all of them to string how can i set it. I have tried "*" character as well as "%" character to select all the fields. but unfortunately it only gets added as a new field to the mapping. How to specify in template to select all the fields under a certain level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a `dynamic_templates` and using `path_match` instead of `match`.  This demonstrates how that might work:

```
curl -DELETE localhost:9200/test-*
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/_template/test
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/_template/test -d '
{
    "template": "test-*",
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
            {
                "level1_level2_all": {
                    "path_match": "level1.level2.*",
                    "match_mapping_type": "*",
                    "mapping": {
                        "index": "not_analyzed",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}
'

curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/test-1/a -d '
{
    "level1": {
        "level2": {
            "x":1
        }
    }
}'
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/test-1/a -d '
{
    "level1": {
        "level2": {
            "y":1
        }
    }
}'

curl http://localhost:9200/test-1/_mapping?pretty
```

The output of which is:

```
  "test-1" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "_default_" : {
        "dynamic_templates" : [ {
          "level1_level2_all" : {
            "mapping" : {
              "index" : "not_analyzed",
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "match_mapping_type" : "*",
            "path_match" : "level1.level2.*"
          }
        } ],
        "properties" : { }
      },
      "a" : {
        "dynamic_templates" : [ {
          "level1_level2_all" : {
            "mapping" : {
              "index" : "not_analyzed",
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "match_mapping_type" : "*",
            "path_match" : "level1.level2.*"
          }
        } ],
        "properties" : {
          "level1" : {
            "properties" : {
              "level2" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "x" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "y" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above approach first. But it so happens that for the first document it receives it sets the type to string, but for the fields which are blank or have no value it sets it to object and then the next document which has values for those blank fields it throws error.

Comment: You need to delete the index and reload the data to get it to take the template

Comment: Yes thats what i did and it is taking the template, but for the case as i've mentioned above it initially sets empty fields as object data type and then when the next document arrives with field value as string / numeric it fails to index it

Comment: Fixed my answer to include `path_match` and a full working example

Comment: Ok..so after repeatedly trying your solution. It seems the issue comes in this use case..lets say in the first document that u send the value is blank i.e for "x" there is no value being sent..so ES will set "x" fields data type as object and then when the second document comes with some value it will try to convert it the respective data type and fail with exception: "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"object mapping for [level1.level2.x] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value"}}}

Comment: I think I understand what's going on. You have a structure where level1.level2=null and so it's turning it into a simple field instead of an object. If level2 will always be an object, you could add a path match to match level1 and set anything at that level to be an object. If you need help with that, update your question to have a minimal example of your test data

Comment: You can't have the same level of name in elasticsearch be both a field with a concrete value and a object container.  So if one record has `level1.level2=a` and another has `level1.level2.level3=b`, it's not possible to store that as a mapped object with fields... `level2` can be an object or a concrete field, but not both.

Comment: In your example for the first document if you send level1.level2.x= blank/ null (or whatever is ES equivalent) and then in the second document you send level1.level2.x="Alcanzar" then what do you get? I get the above error pasted. On checking the mapping after that the data type for x is set to object, whereas it should have been string.

Comment: What version of elasticsearch are you using?  The example I pasted above was against 2.3, but I'm pretty sure it should work on nearly any version.  And yes, no matter what I pass in for x/y, the final mapping has them as string because of the template.

Comment: I am using 2.4.x version of ES..i'll try to lower ES version and give it a shot

Comment: it should work with 2.4.  When you check the mapping of your index after it's created, does it show the dynamic templates?

Comment: Fantastic works in 2.3.x version. Thanks a lot @Alcanzar for your help and patience